# Eigenfunction expansion of neumann problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the problem $\nabla^2u(x,y) = f(x,y)$ on a rectangle  $\Omega =
 [0,1]\times[0,1]$ with homogeneous Neumann boundary conditions along the edges of the rectangle except along the edge $y=1$, where the boundary condition is given by $u_y(x,1) = c$ for some constant $c$

In order to solve this problem by eigenfunction expansion method, I first wrote

$u = \sum a_{m,n} \phi_{m,n}(x,y)$

where the eigenfunctions are given by $\phi_{m,n}(x,y) = \cos(m \pi x)\cos(n \pi y)$.

Then, I get

$$a_{m,n} = \dfrac{\int_{\Omega}u \phi_{m,n}}{\int_{\Omega}\phi_{m,n} \phi_{m,n}} = -\dfrac{1}{\lambda_{m,n}}\dfrac{\int_{\Omega} \nabla^2u \phi_{m,n}}{\int_{\Omega}\phi_{m,n} \phi_{m,n}}$$.

But, when I computed $\int_\Omega \nabla^2u \phi_{m,n}$ using the Green's identity and the given boundary conditions, I expected to get a boundary term involving the constant $c$, but I only got

$$\int_\Omega f \phi_{m,n} $$ with no boundary terms because

$$\int_{y=1} \phi_{m,n} \nabla u \cdot n  =  \int_{y=1, 0 \leq x \leq 1} \cos(m \pi x)\cos(n \pi y) c = 0$$

So, if I just carry on, the solution that I get does not "reflect" the boundary condition $u_y(x,1) = c$. How is this possible? Why is the solution independent of the constant $c$?

Comment: Hint: Does the boundary term really vanish for all m and n?

Comment: @garserdt216 It does because $\int_{0 \leq x \leq 1} cos(m \pi x) = 0$ for all m and the term involving $n$ is just a constant. Doesn't it?

Comment: The boundary term from Green's identity is the response to the inhomogeneity of the boundary conditions. It should not vanish. I haven't  completely checked your calculation, but I know this for fact.

Comment: @garserdt216 That is why I am confused. But, I do not see what I am doing wrong in my calculation

Comment: recheck your integration by parts via green's first identity. you're missing a term.

Comment: I don't think I am missing a term because  the normal derivatives of the eigenfunctions $\phi_{m,n}$ are zero along the boundaries.

Comment: that's true along three edges of the rectangle

Comment: It is also true along the edge $y = 1$  since $\partial _y \phi_{m,n}(x,1) = 0$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58337/discussion-between-garserdt216-and-nan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to expand the solution as
$$
              u(x,y) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n(y)\cos(n\pi x).
$$
Plugging into $\nabla^2 F(x,y)=f(x,y)$ gives
$$
              \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\{A_n''(y)-n^2\pi^2 A_n(y)\}\cos(n\pi x)= f(x,y) \\
     \{A_n''(y)-n^2\pi^2 A_n(y)\}\int_{0}^{1}\cos^2(n\pi x)dx= \int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)\cos(n\pi x)dx \\
       A_n''(y)-n^2\pi^2 A_n(y)=2\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)\cos(n\pi x)dx.
$$
The condition $u_y(x,0)=0$ translates to conditions
$$
         A_n'(0)=0,\;\;\; n = 0,1,2,3\cdots
$$
And, because $u(x,1)=c$ must be constant, then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n(1)\cos(n\pi x)=c$ must hold for all $0 \le x \le 1$, which gives
\begin{align}
    A_0(1)=c, &\\
    A_n(1)=0, &\; n=1,2,3,\cdots.
\end{align}
The complete descriptions of the ODEs for $A_n$ are:
$$
        A_0''(y) = \int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)dx \\
       A_0'(0)=0,\;\;\; A_0(1) = c
$$
and, for $n \ge 1$,
$$        A_n''(y)-n^2\pi^2 A_n(y) = \int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)\cos(n\pi x)dx \\
         A_n'(0) = 0,\;\;\; A_n(1) = 0.
$$
The $n=0$ is straightforward. For $n > 0$, let $f_n(y)=\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)\cos(n\pi x)dx$. The equations for $A_n$ are
$$
          A_n''(y)-n^2\pi^2 A_n(y) = f_n(y) \\
          A_n'(0)=0,\;\;\; A_n(1) = 0.
$$
This requires variation of parameters to solve. It is convenient to use functions $\cosh(n\pi y)$ and $\sinh(n\pi(y-1))$ for this variation of parameters, which leads to a constant $E$ such that
\begin{align}
         A_n(y)  = E\left[\cosh(n\pi y)\int_{y}^{1}\sinh(n\pi(y'-1))f_n(y')dy' \\
 + \sinh(n\pi(y-1))\int_{0}^{y}\cosh(n\pi y')f_n(y')dy'\right]
\end{align}
The constant $E$ is the recirprocal of a Wronskian, which you can easily work out.